# Get Wordpress to alternate displaying 2 and 1 posts in a row

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to code my homepage to have 2 posts in a row, and then the next row have one post, next row 2 posts, and so on.

I have tried using this article, however every time I try I just get glitches.

https://perishablepress.com/two-column-horizontal-sequence-wordpress-post-order/

If anyone has any coding solutions I would really appreciate it.

This is my current index.php file

```html
<?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) :
$i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else :
the_post(); ?>
<article class="post">
    <div id="left-column">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p>
    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
    </p>
    </div>
</article>

<?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
<div>Alternate content</div>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php $i = 0; rewind_posts(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) :
$i++; if(($i % 2) !== 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else :
the_post(); ?>
<article class="post">
    <div id="right-column">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p>
    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
    </p>
    </div>
</article>


<?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
<div>Alternate content</div>
<?php endif; 

get_footer();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call the_post(); the post index is advanced and the next post data becomes in scope.

Create a new template file in your theme and add a new page using that template;

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: page-2-col
 */

get_header();

$i = 0;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => 1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        if( $i %2 == 1 ) {
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-12">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        else {
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-6">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-6">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
}
else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
get_footer();
```

To add bootstrap, in your functions.php;

```
function learningWordPress_resources() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningWordPress_resources');
```

Comment: I have edited my code in my original question and put the current code I'm trying to make work.  I have combined my original code with the code from the website tutorial.  It does not work at all, nothing on my website changes.

Comment: I've updated my answer slightly, using that what result do you get?

Comment: I would put the code you suggested in my index.php file, correct?  Also I'm assuming I should add some css to my style.css file?  I added the suggested coding to my index file and nothing changed on my site.  The posts are still appearing in just the generic vertical one on top of the other.  Thank you so much for you help, I'm still not the best at coding.

Comment: Can you post a link to your site?

Comment: It is on a local host.  I have attached a dropbox folder link where I have attached all of my files, and a screenshot of what my site currently looks like. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hfrohqxz7olqlk6/AAAjQcr0RXawsJb7t3nV-5i8a?dl=0

Comment: ok, so with your functions.php updated to the above you will see the posts listed in the required format, although i would recommend downloading the bootstrap and including it in your project rather than relying on the CDN

Comment: I added the above function to my functions.php file but now my website went blank.  I am downloading bootstrap right now to see if that will fix the problem.

Comment: put define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); at the top of functions.php

Comment: I downloaded bootstrap and nothing changed the web site is still blank.  I also added define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); at the top of my functions.php file.

Comment: Heres a dropbox of your theme as i have altered it and its working without errors for me https://www.dropbox.com/sh/up5l0ohcpeg4c3v/AABP5tZQCQU9ETszDoOVGCWta?dl=0

Comment: It is almost perfect.  The posts line up how I want them (2 on one row, 1 on next, 2 on next) but they appear in the footer.  Do you have any solutions, I'm assuming it's a problem with the footer file?  I have attached a new dropbox folder with the updated files and a screenshot of how the site looks now.  Again, I can not thank you enough for your help!

Comment: if that worked please accept the answer, the other problems are more to do with your structure and CSS and tho i'd be happy to help, the comments for this question arent the right place to do so

Comment: I think I forgot to include the link in the above comment.  If you see the screenshot the posts appear inside the footer menu not in the body area?  So your solution did work, but it just put the posts in the wrong spot. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jvafvxqylg8wuye/AACSatmJfpbLa02-bsbn0yH6a?dl=0

Comment: its not in the footer, it appears that way because of the structure of your page and the CSS you have applied, just empty your stylesheet and you will see, but as i previously said, thats another question entirely

Comment: Thanks for your help, I see the problem!